# Match against type in Haskell typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm not sure how to phrase this exactly so if someone has a good name for it please let me know.

I'm trying to write a typeclass called `Matchable`. The idea is a couple different types of regular expressions that I have (`RegExp a`, `ComplexRegex a`) should be able to match on input.

So I tried this:

```
class Matchable a where
  --   regex, input, success
  match :: a -> b -> Bool
```

But what I really want is to deconstruct the constructor in the typeclass with a type constructor variable or something:

```
class Matchable a where
  --   regex, input, success
  match :: (B a) -> [a] -> Bool
```

That way I can have a `RegExp Char` and a `ComplexRegex Char` both match on a `String`. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want. Can you provide a few type signatures for the different cases of `match` you'd like to abstract? e.g. `matchRegExp :: RegExp Char -> [Char] -> Bool`, `matchComplexReg :: ComplexRegex ...` etc.

Comment: you likely want either associated types (newer, more verbose) or fundeps (older, less verbose) but it's hard to say without actual code

Comment: @jberryman and haoformayor see Alec's answer -- pretty much exactly that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping things simple, why not just make the class variable of `Matchable` have kind `* -> *`? (See `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, `Foldable`, `Traversable` for other examples of higher-kinder classes).

```
class Matchable b where
  --   regex, input, success
  match :: b a -> [a] -> Bool

instance Matchable ComplexRegex where
  -- match :: ComplexRegex a -> [a] -> Bool
  match = error "unimplemented"

instance Matchable RegExp where
  -- match :: RegExp a -> [a] -> Bool
  match = error "unimplemented"
```

Then, you can match against a `String ~ [Char]` with either a `ComplexRegex Char` or a `RegExp Char`.

Comment: N.B. You probably want at least `(Eq a) => b a -> [a] -> Bool`, otherwise `match` doesn't have any structure to work with in `a`.

Comment: This is excellent -- thank you! Is there a way to put the type constraint `Eq a` in the class as opposed to the function `match`?

Comment: @tokknoiagi, I suppose you could add a method `matchableEq :: b a -> Dict (Eq a)` to the class (where `Dict` is from [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict)), which says that if `b` is `Matchable` then `b a` always comes with an `Eq a` dictionary.  But this would be pretty unorthodox design (fun to play with though).  `match :: (Eq a) => ...` seems completely reasonable.

Comment: Thanks! I agree; this seems quite clean cut.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Alec's solution, you could use [associated types](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#An_associated_data_type_example). This allows types which don't have kind `* -> *`, but if it isn't necessary, I'd go with the simpler solution. E.g. imagine that in addition to `RegExp a` and `ComplexRegex a` you have `StringRegex` with is not parametrized, or maybe you can only implement `match` for `ComplexRegex Char` and not `ComplexRegex a`:

```
class Matchable b where
  type Target b :: *
  --   regex, input, success
  match :: b -> [Target b] -> Bool

instance Eq a => Matchable (ComplexRegex a) where
  type Target (ComplexRegex a) = a
  -- match :: ComplexRegex a -> [a] -> Bool
  match = error "unimplemented"

instance Matchable StringRegex where
  type Target StringRegex = Char
  -- match :: StringRegex -> [Char] -> Bool
  match = error "unimplemented"

-- requires FlexibleInstances
instance Matchable (ComplexRegex Char) where
  type Target (ComplexRegex Char) = Char
  -- match :: ComplexRegex Char -> [Char] -> Bool
  match = error "unimplemented"
```

Another difference is that your instances can ensure `Eq (Target b)`, instead of putting it into type of `match` (and you can also make it a requirement: `class Eq (Target b) => Matchable b where ...`).

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from another instance example such as `instance Matchable StringRegex where { type Target StringRegex = Char ... }`.

Comment: @Alec Yes, I neglected it originally.

Comment: Another small detail: this approach lets you have different constraints on the `Target` type for each instance - not just on the class.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for higher-kinded types. If you only interested in `Char` and `String` and behavior of function depends only on whether it's `RegExp` or `ComplexRegex` then you can define next type class:

```
class Matchable r where
  --   regex, input, success
  match :: r Char -> String -> Bool
```

Here `r` is type variable that has kind `* -> *`. In simple words, it's an *incomplete type*. Like `Maybe`. Your function can't have type `Maybe -> Int` because `Maybe` is incomplete type but `Maybe Bool` is complete type. Similar with regular expressions: `RegExp` and `ComplexRegex` are both incomplete types. Thanks to Haskell reach type system your functions can be parametrized over incomplete types as well. So later when you define instances, you will write them in the next way:

```
instance Matchable RegExp where
   ... -- implementation for RegExp goes here

instance Matchable ComplexRegex where
   ... -- implementation for CompltexRegex goes here
```

You can find `-XKindSignatures` and `-XInstanceSigs` language extensions helpful when specifying types of functions and types of types explicitly.

Comment: This is a strange class.  There is no loss of expressivity to just use the simple `match :: r -> String -> Bool` at this point, because the type argument isn't being used in a polymorphic way.

Comment: @luqui I agree that having `match :: r a -> [a] -> Bool` function may be more useful as a more polymorphic variant. But probably for beginner it's easier to start with less polymorphic version if this type of solution will be accepted.

Comment: @Shersh Why not go all the way and have `match :: r -> String -> Bool` and just turn on `FlexibleInstances`? Seems like that, if anything, would be simpler.

Comment: @Alec If you care about only `Char` then `match :: r -> String -> Bool` may be a reasonable alternative. I can't argue which approach is better, just trying to avoid some extensions if possible :) But `r Char` is one step closer to the more polymorphic version which is eventually will be the right choice. Answer was about higher-kinded types which solves problem.